# Any way to get Child Relationships without being bound by user permissions?

Tags: permissions, relationships, describesobject, platform-bug, childrelationship

### Question

User object-level permissions limit the results of `DescribeSObjectResult.getChildRelationships()`.  Are there any workarounds?

I have submitted an Idea about this (https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CZLzQAO).

(**Note:** This seems very closely related to the "Fixed" Known Issue [In API version 44, DescribeSObjectResult.getChildRelationships() checks Read Access to the child entity and parent relationship field](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RX31QAG))

### Actual goal

I would like to dynamically generate a query on `Case`, and several child objects.  E.g.:  `SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, CaseId FROM WorkOrders) FROM Case WHERE ...` I would like to pass in the child SObjectTypes (`WorkOrder.getSObjectType()`) without worrying about the exact fields and the names of the relationship.  Apex provides exactly one path to get the names of child relationships, and it all starts with `SObjectType.Case.getChildRelationships()`.

However, it looks like this is user-permissions dependent, even in a trigger context, which makes it worthless for my goal.

### Description

In Spring '19 (and maybe before -- I have no idea), running `getChildRelationships()` will not return a relationship if the executing user does not have `allowRead` permissions on the child SObject.

(I describe this by example, below.)

I believe this is a bug because [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_permissions.htm) says (emphasis mine):

> Apex classes and triggers run in system mode. Classes and triggers have no restrictions on dynamically looking up any sObject that is available in the org. **You can generate a map of all the sObjects for your org regardless of the current user’s permission**, unless you are executing anonymous Apex.

### Sample Code

Below is a simple method that finds the relationship between a `parentSObjectType` and a `childSObjectType`.  It assumes that there is only one relationship between the two and will throw an error otherwise.

```java
public without sharing class SObjectUtils {
  public static ChildRelationship getRelationshipForSObjectType(SObjectType parentSObjType, SObjectType childSObjType) {
    ChildRelationship value;
    for (ChildRelationship rel : parentSObjType.getDescribe().getChildRelationships()) {
      if (childSObjType == rel.getChildSObject()) {
        if (value != null) {
          throw new RelationshipException('Cannot deduce relationship name from ' + parentSObjType + 
                                          '. There is more than one related object of type ' + childSObjType);
        }
        value = rel;
      }
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

Elsewhere in a test, I run:

```java
@isTest
private static class TEST_SObjectUtils {

  static User getUserWithoutWorkOrderPermissions() {
    // return a user without workorder object permissions
  }

  static User getUserWithWorkOrderPermissions() {
    // return a user with workorder object permissions
  }

  @isTest
  static void worksForUserWithWorkOrderPermissions() {
    ChildRelationship rel;
    System.runAs(getUserWithWorkOrderPermissions()) {
      Test.startTest();

        rel = SObjectUtils.getRelationshipForSObjectType(
          Case.getSObjectType(), 
          WorkOrder.getSObjectType()
        );

      Test.stopTest();
    }
    System.assertEquals('WorkOrders', rel.getRelationshipName());
  }


  @isTest
  static void worksForUserWithoutWorkOrderPermissions() {
    ChildRelationship rel;
    System.runAs(getUserWithoutWorkOrderPermissions()) {
      Test.startTest();

        rel = SObjectUtils.getRelationshipForSObjectType(
          Case.getSObjectType(), 
          WorkOrder.getSObjectType()
        );

      Test.stopTest();
    }
    System.assertNotEquals(null, rel); // this fails!!
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be related to this [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RX31QAG)

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you directly invoke the unit test while logged in as a user who cannot see Work Order, but *don't* use `System.runAs()`, does the observed behavior change?

Comment: @DavidReed Good question -- I think I've spent as much time as I can on this, but it should be fairly easy to test on your end

Comment: @DavidReed It seems you need to be a premier customer to submit a bug report.  Is there any way you can submit this?  It does seem to render `getChildRelationships()` useless (even if it works but is untestable, which I do not think is the issue).

Answer (score 1):

The error here was described in this Known Issue introduce in Winter '19:

[In API version 44, DescribeSObjectResult.getChildRelationships() checks Read Access to the child entity and parent relationship field](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RX31QAG).

The bug is marked Fixed in Spring '19 patch 8.0.  My SObjectUtils class was running in v44.0.  When I upgrade the API version, the issue was not resolved.

I believe that the field-level security issues described in the above ticket may be fixed, but this bug has to do with object-level security.